# How to avoid ticks and labels from overlapping

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks, frame, axeslabel

Consider the following code

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000], AspectRatio -> 1/6,   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 800, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0,   FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc, None}, {tickFunc, None}}]
```

where `tickFunc` is a customized ticks function, given by

```
tickFunc = MapAt[Reverse, {All, 3}]@*Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, "TicksLength" -> {.018, .008}];
```

The plot looks like

[image]

The ticks in the x-axis and their labels slightly overlap. Is there any way to adjust my code and fix this? I am aware of `TickLabelPositioning`, but I am unsure whether this can be used within `Frame`. I am using Mathematica 13.2.0 on Windows 11.

Comment: On *Mathematica* 13.3.0.0 Windows 10 the x-axis ticks look fine:  no overlap with major tick marks.

Comment: Same here. No issues on 13.3.0. with macOSX 13.5

Comment: @JimB Interesting, I will update Mathematica and see. I was using Mathematica 13.2.0, for no particular reason.

Comment: In 13.3.0 seems to work just fine indeed, I edited the question to specify this issue was found in Mathematica 13.2.0.

Comment: For me Mma 13.2 Win 10 it works without overlapping.